# CORS preflighting to WebAPI2 not returning correct headers

Tags: angularjs, cors

I've been fighting a CORS issue for a few days now and I'm stuck.   I've got an angular app trying to do a simple HTTP Post of Json data.

I've gone down the route described here: [ASP.NET Web API - CORS Support in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx) With a custom factory, and I've set my web.config up as:

```
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
```

My $http post call:

```
            var serviceEndpoint = "https://mybox/ourservices/myservices/1.0.0.1/api/process";

        var requestData ={'FirstName':'Nick','LastName':'Jacobs'};

        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: serviceEndpoint,
            withCredentials: true,
            data: requestData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept':'application/json'
            }
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // I need to pick off the user name from the JSON that's returned.
            console.log(data);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
```

The thing is, I see the pre-flight request to the server, it's passing my origin, and asking for appropriate headers, but I get none of the CORS response headers back.   If I go into the web.config and add in the allowed-methods, I do see that come back, but since I'm using withCredentials then I can't use a wild card origins response header, and I was hoping the factory described in the MSDN document above would have solved my problem.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks eveyrbody!

Comment: Tracing is showing me that the request isn't even making it to my code.  It is making it to my server though.   (All full IIS on Win10).

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure CORS in web api application. There are a nuget package for CORS, basically it's an attribute in web api controller and one line configuration in web api config class something like config.EnableCors(). No need any angular configuration. Tks

**MenusItemController.cs**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/menus")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class MenuItemsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post()
    {
        return Ok(new
        {
            Result = "post menus"
        });
    }

    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new
        {
            Result = "get menus"
        });
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

**Nuget Packages**:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
- Microsoft.Owin.Cors
- Microsoft.AspNet.Cors

I published my app and worked fine. I didn't do anything configuration or angular request parameters. Try to GET or POST here: http://www.blocodecodigo.com.br/api/menus.

Comment: something more than config.EnableCors()  and the [EnableCors()] attributes?    We are going down the route in the MSDN article so that we can have a dynamic origin.....